# Use row values as a new column and fill down to their corresponding values

Tags: powerquery

I'm relatively new to Power Query and trying to clean some data. Here's a sample dataset within Power Query.
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q10JS.png)

I need to create a new column called "Standards" and assign values such as 1.1-Governance, 2.1-Consumers, 3.1-Flows, 4.1-Workplace based on their respective documents. Subsequently, I need to remove these values from the "Document NO" column.The desired result would be something like the image below.
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl6ls.png)

Comment: Did any of these answers help at all? If so, please upvote that answer and then accept it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
=if [Title]=null then [Document NO] else null
```

right click that new column and fill down

Use arrow atop the Title column to bring up filter box, and uncheck [ ] null

[image]

Full sample code from home ... advanced editor...:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Standards", each if [Title]=null then [Document NO] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Standards"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Title] <> null))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like horseyride's answer. As an alternative, albeit more complex solution you could try the following:

Add the new Standards column by looking at the Document NO column and returning a value only where the entry in that column starts with a number.

The Text.Start([Document NO], 1) function will return the first character (hence the 1) of the Document NO column for each row and comparing that with the list of all numbers, 0-9).

Then fill down the values in this new Standards column.

Finally remove the null entries from the Version column which essentially removes the document title rows from the Document NO column.

Full code from which can be pasted into the Advanced Editor:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

// Add the Standards Column by looking at Document NO column and repeating the entry where the entry starts with a number
// Otherwise return a null
AddColumn = Table.AddColumn( 
                Source, 
                "Standards",
                each if 
                    List.Contains( {"0".."9"}, Text.Start( [Document NO], 1) ) 
                    then [Document NO] 
                    else null
                ),

// Then fill down in the Standards column
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(AddColumn,{"Standards"}),

// Remove the rows which have null in the version column which essentially removes the Document titles from the Document NO column
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Version] <> null)) in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: In addition to being more complex, your code also is completely dependent on the values to become the `Standard` all starting with a digit, and also that none of the `document NO` values will ever start with a digit. For that reason, I think @horseyride 's solution is significantly more robust, as it depends only on the structure of the data set.

Comment: Oh yeah agree 100% with this @RonRosenfeld. Apologies I didn't make this clear, I'm very new to this. Will try to do better next time.